# DateTimeField queryset returning None in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create a queryset for getting the values of a DateTimeField which is DATETIME in the DB.

The class in models.py:

```
class ChangeMetrics(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    file_id = models.ForeignKey(File, db_column = 'file_id')
    version_id = models.ForeignKey(Version, db_column = 'version_id')
    function_id = models.ForeignKey(Function, blank=True, db_column = 'function_id')
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.TextField(blank=True)
    changed = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The field in the DB:

```
date DATETIME
```

The tuples are populated in the database and running SQL queries directly on the DB is working perfectly.

This is the queryset I am currently using in Django:

```
queryset = ChangeMetrics.objects.filter(~Q(changed=None), ~Q(date=None), ~Q(version_id=None))
```

I have tried a raw query and also a version of the query that uses exclude(), but that still returns None for date.

I am accessing the entries in the queryset through a for loop and simply accessing date through entry.date inside the for loop.

Edit: 
Django version 1.6.5
I have also tried getting the values through the Django shell, to no success.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: What happens if you just query for the null dates on their own?

Comment: Same result, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure if you were able to figure this out, but I just had this problem and was able to fix it.

So, Django migrations were creating the column in the DB as datetime(6) instead of datetime. This was causing the Django models to fail to instantiate the Datetime object.

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` 
MODIFY COLUMN `created` datetime NOT NULL
```

After running that if fixed my issue. Maybe in your case you could try modifying to datetime(6) instead.

Comment: In my case the column was just `datetime`, but still this solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We had this same issue popup while pushing code from local environment (Mac OS X) up to App Engine. While altering the fields like Alexander mentioned to be DATETIME instead of DATETIME(6) did start making them appear, we lost the microseconds. Ended up realizing that in local environment we were running MySQLdb 1.2.5 but when deploying to App Engine, even though we had specified "latest" as the version of MySQLdb, it was only pulling 1.2.4b4, hard-coding to 1.2.5 fixed the issue.

Comment: I ran into this issue with the same local/production environment. Your fix worked like a charm. Didn't know app engine was pulling 1.2.4b4 instead of 1.2.5. Thanks so much @jturmel !

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this solution:

```
queryset = list(ChangeMetrics.objects.filter(changed__isnull=False, date__isnull=False, version_id__isnull=False))
```

Comment: I get the same results with your query.

I can add that the query returns the correct tuples of the DB, i.e. the ones that don't have null in the specified fields. It's only that it doesn't fetch the value of date for some reason.

Comment: Please show your full models.py I mean full `ChangeMetrics` class

Comment: add above comment in your question please @user3063424

Comment: I added it to the main post.

Comment: There is no such an attribute as `changed`

Comment: Sorry, missed the last line. Added it to the question.

Comment: Can you please first check if query with only `changed` attribute is working? Then add for example `date` and after that `version_id` it will be easier to help you

Comment: Changed and version_id work fine. It returns the correct value for every tuple.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Try to move the databse out of your folder, then run `python manage.py syncdb` and check if your database is created correctly according to the Models.

Doesn't work :
Maybe you can try with this (I don't know if it works, I can't try it now) :

```
queryset = ChangeMetrics.objects.filter(changed!=None, date!=None, version_id!=None)
```

Comment: Tried it. I don't think there is a problem with the query itself... Right now I'm thinking that there is something wrong in the linking between models and database.

Comment: Tried that. And ran a new inspectdb > models.py to generate a fresh models file, still returns None.

I'm checking table generations of the db now to see if the error might be there.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by an outdated version of `MySQL-python` not by Django or migrations system.

Using `mysqlclient` (which is an updated fork of `MySQL-python`) solves this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you generate (django migrate command) your database schema on mac. Try to delete the schema and re-migrate from a windows machine.