# Django returning none datetimefield with Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, ubuntu

i have this model:

```
class CalendarEvent(models.Model):
"""
Calendar Events
"""
CSS_CLASS_CHOICES = (
    ('', _('Normal')),
    ('event-warning', _('Warning')),
    ('event-info', _('Info')),
    ('event-success', _('Success')),
    ('event-inverse', _('Inverse')),
    ('event-special', _('Special')),
    ('event-important', _('Important')),
)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Título'))
    comentario = models.TextField('Comentario', blank=True, null=True)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, blank=True, verbose_name='Cliente' ,null=True)
    empleado = models.ForeignKey(Empleado, blank=True, verbose_name='Empleado' ,null=True)
    url = models.URLField(verbose_name=_('URL'), null=True, blank=True)
    css_class = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=_('Tipo'),null=True, blank=True,choices=CSS_CLASS_CHOICES)
    start = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('Inicio'))
    end = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('Término'), null=True, blank=True)
```

Im working on Mac os x with MySQL 5.6.21 and everything is ok, when i get a query asking for the start or end time the response its ok.

> > > from Artico.models import CalendarEvent
> > >
> > > q = CalendarEvent.objects.get(id=90)
> > >
> > > print q.start
> > >
> > > 2015-09-14 01:50:08+00:00

Then i upload my app to an instance with ubuntu on amazon. This instance have Mysql 5.6.19 and Django 1.8.3

I have the same data on Mysql and get this on the query:

> > > from Artico.models import CalendarEvent
> > >
> > > q = CalendarEvent.objects.get(id=90)
> > >
> > > print q.start
> > >
> > > none
> > >
> > > print q.title
> > >
> > > El titulo

then my question is why is occurring this issue? what i have bad if i have the same code on my pc and the amazon instance? is the version of mysql?

Thanks

Comment: What do you get if you run the query is SQL e.g. `select start from artico_calendarevent where id=90`? How did you export the data from your local to remote database?

Comment: on the ubuntu SQL i get : "2015-09-14 01:50:08.000000" and in the OS X SQL i get "2015-09-14 01:50:08.000000"

Comment: i fix it, changing the Length of the ditetime on my SQL i don't know why, but it work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think because django creating the column in the DB as datetime(6) instead of datetime. you can alter the column to datetime.

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` 
MODIFY COLUMN `created` datetime NOT NULL
```

see this: [DateTimeField queryset returning None in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548902/datetimefield-queryset-returning-none-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Remove you database schema, recreate it. And re-migrate it from WINDOWS machine instead of mac.