# Django DateTimeField value lost after thread ends

Tags: mysql, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Below is my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Within the request of creating a **MyModel**, I logged and saw *created* and *modified* is getting default value, current date and time.

Also, from SQL shell, I see the same values are saved in table for **MySQL**.

Nevertheless, when I read the object I created from a new request, every other fields of the model stayed the same, but *created* and *modified* return NULL.

This does not happen on development environment. I am using Google App Engine and Google Cloud SQL 2nd generation for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548902/datetimefield-queryset-returning-none-in-django).

Answer by @jturmel on the question was solution for this problem.

In summary, since MySQL 5.6.4, there was backward incompatible upgrade in DATETIME type. You need MySQLdb version 1.2.5 to work with the new DATETIME.