# When accessing data (DateTimeField) from the django model, it always return None

Tags: python, django, django-models

I hava a model like this one:

```
class PostDetail(models.Model):
    topic_id = models.IntegerField()  
    post_user_id = models.IntegerField()  
    content = models.TextField()  
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-date",)
```

I hava a test table like this:
[image: table]

but when I access data in this way:

```
main_reply = PostDetail.objects.filter(topic_id=id)
print(main_reply[0].date)
```

It always return **None**, I am really confuse

ps: When I access it in SQL, it is alright.

Comment: Is main_reply a queryset? Have you tried to access other fields? and is there only object with topic_id=id ?

Comment: @danish_wani other fields are alright, only this field

Comment: I hava try other ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548902/datetimefield-queryset-returning-none-in-django), but it can not solve this problem

Comment: Is there only one record in your table?

Comment: moreover it should be timezone.now(), now is method not attribute

Comment: try modifying your field from date to created_date may be?

Comment: @danish_wani  I have try other records, but the **date** field never works,**timezone.now**  is  the **right** one, you can see from **django.contrib.auth.models**, and know how it realizes

Comment: i'm talking about the field name not the datatype, DateTimeField is fine. and yeah my bad timezone.now is fine when we use it for modelfield default value

Comment: try renaming the field. and from the screenshot of table record date value does not look like date time value

Comment: @danish_wani  change the field name does no help, I have tried it

Comment: did you run migrations?

Comment: @danish_wani of course yeah,

Comment: can you please print(main_reply.query) and update what sql query it prints.

Comment: @danish_wani sorry, so late to reply you because of the offline,.   The output is: **SELECT "post_postdetail"."id", "post_postdetail"."topic_id", "post_postdetail"."post_user_id", "post_postdetail"."content", "post_postdetail"."create_date" FROM "post_postdetail" WHERE "post_postdetail"."topic_id" = 1 ORDER BY "post_postdetail"."create_date" DESC**

Comment: try to run same query from database shell

Comment: @danish_wani As I had tried before(and just now too), it is fine with database shell, but in django model, when I access this , it returns None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use pycharm to insert the data, it occurs errors like above, but if I use the django admin web to insert data, it works alright, and if user post the data to insert the data, it works fine